# AppleScript Application - Path of folder in 'Supporting Files'

Tags: applescript, xcode

My program needs to copy a folder from its own directory to another on the Mac.

I have tried everything and looked in all corners of the web but can't get the path to this folder:

[image: Photo of folder whose path is required]

I have searched similar posts and found this:

```
set thePath to POSIX path of (path to resource "name of resource")
```

It works for files but not folders.

Can this be adapted to get the path to the folder selected in the image above?

Answer (score 1):

The "Folders" in the Xcode sidebar are "groups" and not filesystem entities. In your project there is no "Supporting Files" folder on disk.

That said, you might try putting a dummy file in your target folder on disk, adding it to the project, and using the snippet you found to get a posix path to the dummy file. Which you can shorten to get the path to the target folder. You would want to remove the dummy file after you copied the folder of course.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit Late but have you tried:

```
NSBundle* myBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString* myfilenamewpath = [myBundle pathForResource:@"Filename" ofType:@"typeoffile"];
//get the filename
NSString *theFileName = [myfilenamewpath lastPathComponent] ;
//get the path
NSString *filePath = [myfilenamewpath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];

NSLog(@"myfilenamewpath: %@", myfilenamewpath);
NSLog(@"theFileName: %@", theFileName);
NSLog(@"filePath: %@", filePath);
```